# Unable to get all changed files details using GITLAB API

Tags: gitlab, git-commit

I have 29 changed files in one commit id and when I try to get all the details using below GitLab API then I am not getting all the files.
I am getting only 18 file details.

I tried with `per_page=100&page=1` parameter but still not getting all changes.

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/diff`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#get-the-diff-of-a-commit) API is for getting the diff of a commit, check first locally (using [`git show --pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats)) if you do see  29 or 18 files in the same commit present on your local cloned repo:

```
git show --compact-summary <SHA1>
```

If you don't see all the files there (meaning locally, not through GitLab) then some of some files were changed in other commits.

Comment: I see 29 files with your command in local. I need to clone a repository or download a  commit from a c# application. i am not able to download all files.

Comment: @Asma Strange: the API should return the same diff as a local git show. Maybe the diff portion of the JSON response is limited in length.

Comment: @Asma What is the length of that `diff` field in your JSON response? (to check if it is 32768 (https://www.binary-code.org/binary/18bit/001000000000000000/) or other length close to a binary limit)